# What is a better way to manage same database tables for multiple products/environment?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, database-design

I have multiple products/environment, like Google has drive, docs etc.
One common Auth server is there which will contain users table.

But I have roles table related to each product, which contains roles for user for respective product.

Now how to manage this roles table?
I have following ways to do this, which one is better and why?

1. Create common table `roles` in main schema, and have product ID to link the records in table.
2. Have different table in same schema with prefix product_name.         Eg. prod1_roles, prod2_roles.
3. Have different schema in same database, for Eg. product1 schema contains product1 roles table and so on.

Which of the above approach should I go with? Creating different database for 1 table is not feasible for me. So I want to go with any one of above or any other better approach will be appreciated.

Comment: First option is better.You have to maintain  only 1 table.

Comment: First one is preferable.

Comment: @MDanish, any reason why should I use 1st? As in future I will have so many roles and products so club all at one place won't it make database performance issue?Searching will be slow, isn't it?

Comment: @Nitika , any reason why should I use 1st? As in future I will have so many roles and products so club all at one place won't it make database performance issue?Searching will be slow, isn't it?

Comment: In Second option you have to create new table with new product.

Comment: Im already working data level security role base, Have never performance issue even we retrieve thousands rows role wise, its a small penalty. no issue. Second  approach is messy.

Comment: @MDanish ok so what about 3rd approach?

Comment: If you have 100 Product then  create 100 Schema and so on...It create complexity in  your DB.

Answer (score 3):

If all your tables could have the same columns, is better to have just one, in a central schema, using an product_id. You will use the same pattern for login all your users at different products. This make your security layer easyer to control. And this is an important feature.